# Using otto for inter fragment communication - dependency injection confusing

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-fragments, singleton, otto

I wish to use Otto for inter-fragment communication. I want to do this using best practices if I can help it. The Otto example on Github uses a singleton for the `Bus` object, but recommends using dependency injection. I'm new to both of these concepts, although the former appears to be easier to implement. I'm struggling to see how I would do the latter without considerable effort, despite reading around.

There are the OS dependency injectors dagger, guice and a few others, but they seem like they would be fairly heavy going for a relative newbie like myself to pick up. I'm wondering if it is really worth it learning to use one of these for seemingly minor gains in efficiency/code conventionality. Not to mention that they will bloat my project.

Is it really worth it to implement Otto using DI, when I am only going to be using it to replace a few interfaces and listeners here and there? I'll only really be registering the `Bus` in a few fragment-containing activities

I won't be unit testing, and I can live with two or three activities (out of ten) being tightly coupled to their fragments. I can't see anything *really* bad in doing this, much as it is ill advised, especially if it is relatively easy to switch to dependency injection later on.

Lastly, do I need separate `Bus` instances for seperate activity-fragment groups, where communication will only occur within said groups? Its not clear to me from reading whether I need to do this for best practice/efficiency or safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you might get different opinions on this, but having used Otto and dagger myself, and considering the information you provided, I don't think the cost/benefit of implementing DI (with dagger, guice, or something else) would be worth it for you.  This is not a knock on dagger - I like it and am using it successfully, but there's a learning curve, and if you're not doing unit testing, I don't know that it would provide much value to you.

If you begin to do unit testing later, then adding DI would be a good move.

Regarding the question of separate `Bus` instances for separate activity-fragment groups, that may not be necessary if those activities-fragment groups are not publishing and subscribing to the same kinds of events.  That is, if activity-fragment group A only cares about Foo events, and activity-fragment group B only cares about Bar events, then I think a single Application-scope `Bus` might meet your needs.

Comment: I agree, though I think it might be an idea for me to learn unit testing at some point, especially for the sake of many-activity apps. Learning aspect aside, it does seem like it would be relatively easy to switch to something like Dagger in the future anyway.